# Three.js .Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. Vector3 (Where and why?)

Tags: javascript, three.js

This code has been frustrating, I'm trying to make a spinning cube and I keep getting errors. My code in camera.js and scene.js:

```
import * as THREE from "three";

export function createCamera(gameWindow) {
  const DEG2RAD = Math.PI / 180;

  const LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON = 0;
  const MIDDLE_MOUSE_BUTTON = 1;
  const RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON = 2;

  const MIN_CAMERA_RADIUS = 2;
  const MAX_CAMERA_RADIUS = 10;
  const MIN_CAMERA_ELEVATION = 30;
  const MAX_CAMERA_ELEVATION = 90;

  const ROTATION_SENSITIVITY = 0.5;
  const ZOOM_SENSITIVITY = 0.02;
  const PAN_SENSITIVITY = -0.01;

  const Y_AXIS = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);

  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, gameWindow.offsetWidth / gameWindow.offsetHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  let cameraOrigin = new THREE.Vector3();
  let cameraRadius = 4;
  let cameraAzimuth = 0;
  let cameraElevation = 0;
  let isLeftMouseDown = false;
  let isRightMouseDown = false;
  let isMiddleMouseDown = false;
  let prevMouseX = 0;
  let prevMouseY = 0;
  
  updateCameraPosition();

  function onMouseDown(event) {
    if (event.button === LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON) {
      isLeftMouseDown = true;
    }

    if (event.button === MIDDLE_MOUSE_BUTTON) {
      isMiddleMouseDown = true;
    }

    if (event.button === RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON) {
      isRightMouseDown = true;
    }
  }

  function onMouseUp(event) {
    if (event.button === LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON) {
      isLeftMouseDown = false;
    }

    if (event.button === MIDDLE_MOUSE_BUTTON) {
      isMiddleMouseDown = false;
    }

    if (event.button === RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON) {
      isRightMouseDown = false;
    }
  }

  function MouseDown(event) {
    camera.onMouseDown(event);
  }

  function MouseUp(event) {
    camera.onMouseUp(event);
  }

  function MouseMove(event) {
    camera.onMouseDown(event);
  }

  function onMouseMove(event) {

    const deltaX = (event.clientX - prevMouseX);
    const deltaY = (event.clientY - prevMouseY);

    //Rotation
    if (isLeftMouseDown) {
      cameraAzimuth += -(deltaX * ROTATION_SENSITIVITY);
      cameraElevation += (deltaY * ROTATION_SENSITIVITY);
      cameraElevation = Math.min(MAX_CAMERA_ELEVATION, Math.max(MIN_CAMERA_ELEVATION, cameraElevation));
      updateCameraPosition();
    }

    //Panning
    if (isMiddleMouseDown) {
      const forward = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1).applyAxisAngle(Y_AXIS, cameraAzimuth * DEG2RAD);
      const left = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0).applyAxisAngle(Y_AXIS, cameraAzimuth * DEG2RAD);

      cameraOrigin.add(forward.multiplyScalar(PAN_SENSITIVITY * deltaY));
      cameraOrigin.add(left.multiplyScalar(PAN_SENSITIVITY * deltaX));
      updateCameraPosition();
    }

    //Zooming
    if (isRightMouseDown) {
      cameraRadius += deltaY * ZOOM_SENSITIVITY;
      cameraRadius = Math.min(MAX_CAMERA_RADIUS, Math.max(MIN_CAMERA_RADIUS, cameraRadius));
      updateCameraPosition();
    }

    prevMouseX = event.clientX;
    prevMouseY = event.clientY;
  }

    function updateCameraPosition() {
    camera.position.x = cameraRadius * Math.sin(cameraAzimuth * DEG2RAD) * (Math.cos(cameraElevation * DEG2RAD));
    camera.position.y = cameraRadius * Math.sin(cameraElevation * DEG2RAD);
    camera.position.z = cameraRadius * Math.cos(cameraAzimuth * DEG2RAD) * (Math.cos(cameraElevation * DEG2RAD));

    camera.add(cameraOrigin);

    camera.lookAt(cameraOrigin);
    camera.updateMatrix();
  }

  return {
    camera,
    onMouseDown,
    onMouseUp,
    onMouseMove
  }
}

//scene.js

import * as THREE from "https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js";
import { createCamera } from "./camera.js"

export function createScene() {
  const gameWindow = document.getElementById("render-target");
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x777777);

  const camera = createCamera(gameWindow);
  
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(gameWindow.offsetWidth, gameWindow.offsetHeight);
  gameWindow.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 })
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  let meshes = [];

  function initialize(city) {
    
  }


  function draw() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera.camera);
  }

  function start() {
    renderer.setAnimationLoop(draw);
  }

  function stop() {
    renderer.setAnimationLoop(null);
  }

  return {
    start,
    stop,
  }
}
```

I tried to run it and expected a pannable, zoomable, and rotatable cube yet it gave me the error in the title. I instead got a cube stuck in place and an error, I don't get why it's giving me the error and where it's giving me the error. I'm confused and am not that good with three.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:
`camera.add(cameraOrigin);`

The `add` method expects an `Object3D`, you are passing a `Vector3` (`cameraOrigin = new THREE.Vector3();`), hence the error. If you want to set a position to your object, use `.position` instead

Some documentation: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.position